# Convert date format for angular in ie11

Tags: angular

I have date for ie11 like this

**2019-08-08 00:00:00**

I need to convert to be like this

**08/08/2019**

I have used **formatDate from '@angular/common';** but for ie11 it can not be converted?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use **date pipe** in angular In ie11 support Date pipe

```
{{date | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

also you can use moment like below way

```
 import * as moment from 'moment';

 let getDate = moment(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```

Comment: Please post your code. because it working in IE 11 I'm just checking it.

Comment: Try  {{2019-08-08 00:00:00 | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} in ie11, you will get error

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might help you

```
    import { Constants } from './../util/constants';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dateFormat'
})
export class DateFormatPipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return super.transform(value, Constants.DATE_FMT);
  }
}

export class Constants {
  static readonly DATE_FMT = 'dd/MMM/yyyy';  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in `.ts` file like:

```
this.date = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString()
```